# setting SendAs immediately after creating and moving user to OU having Mail service enabled

Tags: google-email-settings-api

I'm using the Google Apps Provisioning API to 1) create new users in our domain and 2), immediately after creation, move them into a sub OU which has the Mail service enabled.  I would also like to use the Mail Settings API to 3) set a default SendAs for the new users at the same time.  However, I don't seem to be able to set the SendAs until a small amount of time has passed.  I get an InvalidValue(1801) ErrorCode.  If I make the same call to the Mail Settings API a little later, it works fine.  So, I'm guessing the problem is when the Mail Settings API call is made, the user hasn't been registered as being in the OU with the Mail service enabled yet.

Is there a way for me to set the SendAs immediately after the user creation and move?  As a workaround, I can put a short delay in my code before the setting of the SendAs, but I'd prefer not to have to do this and I'm not sure what amount of delay would consistently be sufficient.

Thanks for any help you may be able to provide.

Sam LaSala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reasons you are still using the provisioning APi instead of the new Directory API? (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users).  Provisioning API has been deprecated, and it is subjected to the deprecation policy.  It is better if you start using the new API instead of developing your code in the old one.

With the new API, you can actually combine step1 and step2 together where you can directly create the user in the OU that has mail enabled. That way it will eliminate the additional call, and the user will inherit the services that have been already turned on in the OU.  Hope this will resolve the issue you have.

You can also check out the functionalities of the Directory API in the API explorer:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/directory/admin/directory_v1/